# Does anybody know how to combine flip and swipe in a deck in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, combinations, swipe, flip

the user should first flip a card and see the backside and than swipe left or right. Does anybody know how to combine flip deck and swipe in Kotlin?

Flip deck looks like this: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/animation/cardflip.html

Swipe looks like this: https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Comment: What platform is this for?  (This question looks like it's much more about the UI than about Kotlin.)

Comment: What do you mean with platform?

Comment: TornadoFX/JavaFX/Swing, Android, iOS, Xamarin, SWT, Qt, KWeb…  The answer will be specific to which UI platform you're using — and probably not to the Kotlin language.

Comment: Ah got it. It´s for the Android platform.

Answer (score 0):

I want to create a stack for Android in Kotlin which:

1. Which has its Items at the same position (without offset). For example, like Tinder. One just see the first item/image of the stack.
2. I want to add flip and see the backside of the card. Like this: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/animation/cardflip.html
3. After the flip I want to remove the card with a swipe to the left or to the right.

So far I have a stack with the following code:

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.stackview

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val itemList = listOf<Int>(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val stackAdapter = StackAdapter (this, itemList)

        stack_view.adapter = stackAdapter
    }
}
```

**StackAdapter**

```
package com.example.stackview

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.ImageView

class StackAdapter(val context: Context, val list: List<Int>): BaseAdapter(){
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
        val item = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image) as ImageView

        item.setImageResource(list[position])

        return view
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return list[position]
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return list.size
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <StackView
        android:id="@+id/stack_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:loopViews="true"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"/>

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```